# Como modificar datos de componentes "lejanos" en Vue

Tags: vue.js

Como puedo modificar los datos de un componente desde otro componente "lejano"?, cuento con la siguiente estructura:

```
Principal
   importa a secundario_1
       importa a secundario_2
           importa a secundario_3
           | secundario_3 debe modificar datos de Capa
Capa    <---
```

Solo quiero modificar el valor de `abc` de Capa desde secundario_3

```
data:() => ({
    abc: 'hola mundo'
})
```

Intente con `async` y `$emit` pero solo me funciona entre padre e hijo. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un `EventBus` que te ayuda a interactuar entre componentes.
Lo que se hace es crear una nueva instancia de Vue que será utilizada solamente para emitir eventos y recibir esos eventos desde cualquier otro componente.

event-bus.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

En tu secundario_3 lo importas:

```
import { EventBus } from "./event-bus.js";
```

y emites un evento así:

```
EventBus.$emit("modificarDatos", "CAMBIO");
```

Luego en tu Capa recibes ese evento:

```
EventBus.$on("modificarDatos", cambios => {
  console.log("Recibido desde secundario_3", cambios);
  this.abc = cambios;
});
```

Te dejo el [código completo](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-meitner-k1m1q)

Espero te sirva!

Comment: tambien podria usar vuex, o tambien podria levantar un evento en el hijo que levante un evento en su padre y asi hasta llegar a la capa que quiere. Por favor, mira [answer], un comentario y un link se consideran una respuesta de baja calidad